# Pass object as a function parameter

Tags: javascript

**Basis**

- A `toplevelOBJ` object is used throughout the application as `this.toplevelOBJ`, where I have access to it's properties, such as, e.g. `this.toplevelOBJ.mapArea.coordX`.
- In `ClassB` there is a function called `blink` which waits for signal from an outside source.
- In `ClassC` I need to capture this signal, so I set up a function, `capture` in `ClassC` to retrieve the signal sent by `ClassB`

**Problem**

When sent through the `capture()` function to `ClassC`,
`"this"` in `this.toplevelOBJ` no longer refers to the `toplevelOBJ`, but `ClassC`.

Because of this, I sent `this.toplevelOBJ` as parameter `toplevel` through the `capture()` function, but on receiving, I am not sure If a function from the `toplevelOBJ` is being called: `toplevel.update()`, whereas I can access its properties: `toplevel.mapArea.coordX`

**QUESTION**

When sending through an `Object` as a parameter, is the `Object` exactly the same? because when I inspected the `Object`, I found the `update()` function under `toplevel.__proto__.__proto__`, whereas, I found its properties straight away: `toplevel.mapArea`

---

**Code**

```
// Class in which I am sending the object
var ClassB = exports.ClassB = ClassA.extend({
    blink: function(key, value) {
       ClassC.prototype.capture(key, value, this.toplevelOBJ);
    }
});
```

---

```
// Class in which I am receiving the object
var ClassC = exports.ClassC = ClassA.extend({
    capture: function(key, value, toplevel) {
        /* Run Function of toplevel */
    }
});
```

Comment: The value of `this` is determined by the circumstances of every function invocation. To me, that makes your entire question extremely confusing. A "top level object" to me means "global object", in which case there's no need to access it via `this`.

Answer (score 0):

The most common way that this is taken care of in classes is to store the proper `this` at time of instantiation.  The most common way of doing this is as such:

```
function SomeClass
{
 var that = this;
 that.myVariable = 5;

 that.someFunction = function()
 {
    return that.myVariable;
 }
}
```

You also have wrappers/proxy methods, such as explained by the `bind` function in the underscore library, that can 'force' the `this` variable.  See http://underscorejs.org/#bind

I prefer these two methods over *forcing* the `this` variable by the caller.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, when you pass an object as a parameter, it's exactly the same.

It's not even an exact copy of the object, it's actually *the same* object. The parameter is just a reference to the object, so the object is never copied.

---

Properties and methods can either be a member of the object itself or a member in the prototype chain. In your case the `mapArea` property is a member of the object itself, and the `update` method is a member of the prototype or the object that is the prototype of the `toplevelOBJ` object.